# Delete middle vertex

Tags: vertices

I have a lot of vertices that I do not use and I would like to eliminate them. I cannot make the selection one by one, is there an automatic method to eliminate them?
I can't use decimate.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With one of those verts selected, in edit mode, press *Shift+G* for the Select Similar menu, then use *Amount of Connecting Edges* to select those ones. However do a double check if you have other non-manifold geo, this selection might catch other ones like the corners on this plane. But on a fully manifold 3D mesh it should only select those verts. Then dissolve.

Also what @moonboots said with Limited Dissolve, should work in a lot of other situations, but for instance, it doesn't work in my example below, with all the faces on the same plane. Both are equally valid options to try out though.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In your case try a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*, it dissolves all the vertices as long as the edges are below the defined angle:

[image]